# Poblar DataGridView mediante una lista desconectadamente

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Trabajo con Visual Studio 2019, Windows Forms
Necesito poblar un DGV mediante una lista pero recorriendo la lista y poblando el DGV necesito hacerlo desconectadamente si enlazarlo a datos.

```
var listProductoPrecio =
                    _saProductoPrecio.ListaProductoPrecio(Convert.ToInt32(txtListaPrecioId.Text)).ToList();

                foreach (var item in listProductoPrecio)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                    row.CreateCells(dgvProductoPrecio);
                    row.Cells["colProductoPrecioId"].Value = item.ProductoPrecioId;
                    row.Cells["colListaPrecioId"].Value = item.ListaPrecioId;
                    row.Cells["colProductoId"].Value = item.ProductoId;
                    row.Cells["colProducto"].Value = item.NombreProducto;
                    row.Cells["colTipoPrecioId"].Value = item.TipoPrecioId;
                    row.Cells["colProductoPrecio"].Value = item.NombreTipoPrecio;
                    row.Cells["colCantidad"].Value = item.Cantidad;
                    row.Cells["colPrecioCompra"].Value = item.PrecioCompra;
                    row.Cells["colUtilidad"].Value = item.Utilidad;
                    row.Cells["colPvp"].Value = item.Pvp;
                    dgvProductoPrecio.Rows.Add(row);
                }
```

El error que tengo es que entrando al foreach en la primera columna me dice que no encuentra el nombre de la columna pero lo he revisado y esta tal cual.
¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Y si usas el índice de la columna en lugar del nombre? O sea, en lugar de `row.Cells["colProductoPrecioId"].Value = item.ProductoPrecioId;`, usa `row.Cells[0].Value = item.ProductoPrecioId;`, donde 0 es el número de la columna tal cual las definiste.

Answer (score 0):

puedes llenar el datagrid con una fuente de datos. en este caso tienes una lista.

Este es un ejemplo.

```
 var Source = RepositoryDA.GetConteoFaltante(SucursalIdRealizado, txtFaltanteProducto.Text, txtFaltanteFolio.Text);
            this.dgvFaltantes.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            this.dgvFaltantes.DataSource = Source;
```

en tu caso seria nada mas.

```
var listProductoPrecio =               _saProductoPrecio.ListaProductoPrecio(Convert.ToInt32(txtListaPrecioId.Text)).ToList();
dgvProductoPrecio.DataSource = listProductoPrecio;
```

asi llenarias tu datagridview, sin necesidad de recorrer la lista ay agregarla

Espero haberte ayudado!.

Comment: Necesito poblarla de datos desconectadamente(esto quiere decir no enlazado a datos y por lo tanto no puedo usar Datasource). gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado

```
dgvProductoPrecio.Rows.Add(" ", item.ProductoPrecioId, item.ListaPrecioId, item.ProductoId,
                        item.NombreProducto, item.TipoPrecioId, item.NombreTipoPrecio, item.Cantidad,
                        item.PrecioCompra, item.Utilidad, item.Pvp);
```